# Assign new name to a defined function in R

Tags: r

I have two bandwidth functions `bandwidth_a()` and `bandwidth_b()`. Dependent on the task at hand either one needs to be applied. I have other functions which require a bandwidth call.

Is it possible to have my other functions call a generic `bandwidth()` and before the call of those functions set either `bandwidth() <- bandwidth_a()` or `bandwidth() <- bandwidth_b()`?

Or how can this requirement be fulfilled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using `get`

```
>bandwith_a = function() return('A')

>bandwith_b = function() return('B')

>bandwith = get("bandwith_a")

>bandwith()
[1] "A"
>bandwith = get("bandwith_b")

>bandwith()
[1] "B"
```

Also please note that you might have to specify the `environment` if you are calling `get` from inside one function.

Comment: You don't need `get`. You can just do `bandwith = bandwith_a`.

Comment: I can confirm Roland's comment. This should be the solution. One has to use `=` instead of `<-`

Comment: The advantage of using `get` is that it allows you to easily specify the environment of the functions `bandwith_a` and `bandwith_b` reside: `get(x, pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), mode = "any", inherits = TRUE)`

Comment: Why @Friedrich do you say that you cannot use `<-`? I just used it and it works fine (i.e. the name on the LHS of the assignment is a function that can be called to invoke the function on the RHS of the assignment, i.e. same effect as with `=`).

Comment: @mastropi you are right. i might have had mistakenly a variable assigned with the same name, when testing.

Answer (score 2):

Using *match.fun*:

```
bandwidth_a <- function() "A"
bandwidth_b <- function() "B"

x <- "a"
bandwidth <- match.fun(paste0("bandwidth_", x))
bandwidth()
# [1] "A"

x <- "b"
bandwidth <- match.fun(paste0("bandwidth_", x))
bandwidth()
# [1] "B"
```

But I'd prefer a generic function as suggested by [@CatalystRPA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816855/680068)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a `type` argument.

```
    bandwidth <- function(x, type = "a") {
      if(type == "a") {
        result <- bandwidth_a(x)
      } 
      if(type == "b") {
        result <- bandwidth_b(x)
      } 
    result
    }
```

---

In case your behaviour depends on the type (`class`) of the input, you could also define a generic function, check out [Advanced R by Hadley](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html).

> A generic function defines an interface, which uses a different
> implementation depending on the class of an argument (almost always
> the first argument). Many base R functions are generic, including the
> important print()

---

**EDIT** if you just have an R script you'd like to run through command line, another similar solution is to use [Command line arguments](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparse/vignettes/argparse.html) such as:

```
Rscript example.R –type=a
```

Then you'd pass the type as argument to the function.

Comment: To keep the code readable and simple, this solutions is not feasible in my case. I'd need either a global variable or have other function pass this argument, which then would need it as in input etc.

Comment: Okay, but there will always be a need to specify which function you want to actually call. This IMO is best done with an argument, in case you cannot derive the type from the input itself. Anyways good luck

Comment: You are right. In my case, I am just programming an `.R` script, which has to run through, and that's it, so the re-assigment should be ok, even though it might else not be the best style.

Comment: in case you're just running a script from command line, you can use command line arguments, see edits. In case this is not the best style, I know many programmers who've been doing things wrong.